# Create Jekyll link from YAML array

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I have a YAML array in a file called navigation.yml as follows:

```
docs:

- title: Home
  url: index.md
  id: index

- title: Support
  url: support.html
  id: support

- title: About
  url: about.md
  id: about
```

I am creating a navigation bar as follows:

```
<section id="navigation" class="clearfix">
  {% for item in site.data.navigation.docs %}
  <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{% link index.md %}" id="{{ item.id }}" class="navigationButton"><span>{{ item.title }}</span></a>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

What should I put in place of index.md to get the item.url that I want from the YAML file.

I am totally new to GitHub Pages, YAML, and Jekyll.

Comment: Replacing `{% link index.md %}` with `{{ item.url }}` should do it if I understand it correctly.

Comment: That works, but it sends you to a page without the Jekyll theme, which I did not mention that I was using.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the `link` tag doesn't seem to support variables.
There's [a pull request](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6261) trying to change this, but it has not been merged into the main Jekyll repo yet.

So if you want to do this now, you need to use some tricks.

The solution suggested by flyx in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555735/create-jekyll-link-from-yaml-array#comment84112768_48555735) *(replace `{% link index.md %}` by `{{ item.url }}`)* basically works, but shows the original filename written in the data file.

⇒ If `index.md` is automatically renamed to `index.html` while rendering the site, your link won't work anymore.
*(or if `support.html` becomes `support/index.html`)*

That's probably why you wanted to use the `link` tag instead.

Without using the `link` tag, you need to loop your data file, loop through all pages to find the respective page, and show **that page's actual URL** in your link:

```
<section id="navigation" class="clearfix">
  {% for item in site.data.navigation.docs %}
    {% for page in site.pages %}
       {% if page.path == item.url %}
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}" id="{{ item.id }}" class="navigationButton"><span>{{ item.title }}</span></a>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

This even takes stuff like explicitly set permalinks *(`permalink: /whatever/` in the page's front matter)* into account.